# Proper quoting for having sub-variables expand into their own parameters?

Tags: bash

What's the best way to do

```
n=4
file1=firstfile.txt
file2=secondfile.txt
catlist="$file1" "$file2" 'file3.txt file'"$n"'.txt'

cat $catlist
```

Typically the gotchya with quoting is that you don't do enough.  But I actually do want these to be their own parameters, so I'm not really sure how to go about this.

Comment: Can you please give an example of your desired output?

Comment: You are trying to handle spaces within filenames?

Comment: nope, no spaces.  i want to output the contents of each file in the list one after another.

Comment: how about catlist="$file1 $file2 file3.txt file$n.txt"

Comment: If you can do away with the `catlist` variable, things would be much simpler. It seems to serve no useful purpose, but perhaps it does outside of this limited context. `cat "$file1" "$file2" file3.txt "file$n.txt"`

Comment: Yeah, there's additional context going on.  file3 isn't necessarily going to be in the list.  it only gets included in the intermediate list-variable upon the truth of a condition :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never put more than one argument into a single string; you need an array to hold multiple arguments.

```
catlist=( "$file1" "$file2" file3.txt "file$n.txt" )

cat "${catlist[@]}"
```